# How to convert a blob to Excel file using a REST API from Azure storage in Java

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-rest-api

I have a blob file sitting in the Azure Storage container. I have to convert that to a excel and retrieve using REST API. Is this possible?

I heard this is possible by using Azure storage REST API. I tried with below it didn't work

`Method: POST URL: https://<your-storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/<your-container>/file.csv?copy Header: x-ms-version: 2019-02-02, x-ms-copy-destination: <your-container>/file.xlsx Query Parameter: comp:copy`

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "convert" but... there are no file-conversion tools built into Azure Storage. They only thing you *can* do is store content along with a specific ContentType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @David Makogon there is no concept such as file-conversion but all you can do is set the content-type of the blob while performing rest Api. Since blob can be of any type i.e., .png, .csv, .pdf and so on, you may perform file conversions after retrieving the file to your local storage. You can retrieve a blob from blob storage using [GET Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob?tabs=azure-ad)

> ```
> https://<YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net/<YOUR_CONTAINER>/<BLOB_NAME>
> ```

[image]

For more information regarding Blob Storage rest API you can refer this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-rest-api).